# Github Pages Resource 404

Tags: reactjs, github, github-pages

As of now I want to publish my payment gateway website to GitHub pages but after running all the commands like `npm run build` as well `npm run deploy` my page has been published but on GitHub pages it is showing **error for resource**:

[image]

Here is how it looks in my IDE:
[image]

Answer (score -1):

You published your website on a subpath like `xyz.github.io/mysubpath` but the references on the index page (according to the page source) are absolute to the root.

This is even shown in the console output:

> The project was built assuming it is hosted at `/`.

If you cannot move your website to the root, you need to adjust the paths to be either relative (remove the first slash) or include the subpath (e.g. `/mysubpath/favicon.ico`). The framework you are using probably has a way to set the `basepath` or `homepage`.

From the screenshot of your IDE, I see that you seem to use React and therefore can probably change line 2 to `homepage` instead of `home`. Additional information can be found [here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#building-for-relative-paths).